# Takes or take, subject verb agreement

Tags: verb-agreement

**1.** Veronica *takes* a lot of time.

**2.** Let Veronica *take* her time.

Could you guys help me with the grammar rule involved while deciding why we'll use the verb 'take' and not 'takes' in the second sentence?

Comment: I've answered this, but it should really be moved to ELL

Answer (score 1):

*Take* here is not plural: it is the base form of the verb (sometimes called the infinitive).

Finite verb forms like *takes* (and, for that matter *am*, *is*, *are*) are only used when they are the main verb of the clause.

When they are governed by another verb (whether a modal like *can* and *should*, an auxiliary like *be*, *have* and *do*, or one of the harder to classify examples like *let* and *make* and *have to*) they take another form.

In nearly all cases that form is always the base, or infinitive - which for every verb except *be* happens to be the same as the plural form.

So

> Veronica takes a lot of time.

but

> Veronica may *take* a lot of time.
>
> Veronica shouldn't *take* a lot of time.
>
> Veronica needs to *take* a lot of time.
>
> Let Veronica *take* a lot of time.

And for completeness, the exceptions I mentioned:

> Veronica has *taken* a lot of time. (Present perfect)
>
> Veronica is *taking* a lot of time. (Continuous)
>
> Veronica is *taken* to the theatre by her aunt. (Passive)
>
> Veronica gets *taken* to the theatre by her aunt. (Colloquial passive)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the right category and answering the question. At which CEFR level do you think this should be taught?

Comment: Sorry, Samuel, I have no idea what a CEFR level is.